# How can I call $content = str_replace PHP function

Tags: php, function

Long short, I have a function that is responsible for executing specific data from my database, but the problem is I can't use that function. To be more clear:

This is the function

```
function ReplaceHTMLCode_Database($content){
    $content = str_replace('{SELECT_CHAR}',GetPlayerSelect(),$content);
}

function GetPlayerSelect(){
    $QUERY = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query( ConnectiShopDb(),
            "SELECT * from ".ISHOP_MYSQL_DB.".select_char where account_id=('".$_SESSION['ISHOP_SESSION_ID']."')"
    ));

    if($QUERY['pid_id']){
            return GetPlayerInfo($QUERY['pid_id'],'name').
                    "(".GetPlayerRaceByJob(GetPlayerInfo($QUERY['pid_id'],'job')).")";
    } else {
            return "{NO_CHARACTER_LABEL}";
    }
}
```

I hope that I'm not being vague, But I tried `selected="selected">{"SELECT_CHAR"}</option>` in my PHP form that is supposed to be displaying this function and it's just being displayed as `$SELECT_CHAR`. I'm aware that this may be part of WordPress code since

I googled how to use `ReplaceHTMLCode`_Database and figured out it's pretty much something to do with WP, but I'm not using WordPress or any different CMS. Any help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning or changing the variable. It would need to either do this:

```
function ReplaceHTMLCode_Database(&$content){
    $content = str_replace('{SELECT_CHAR}',GetPlayerSelect(),$content);
}
```

This takes the variable by reference and changes it. You could then use it like so:

```
ReplaceHTMLCode_Database($content);
```

Otherwise, you could do this:

```
function ReplaceHTMLCode_Database($content){
    return str_replace('{SELECT_CHAR}',GetPlayerSelect(),$content);
}
```

Which returns a new value that you could assign somewhere, like this:

```
$content = ReplaceHTMLCode_Database($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ReplaceHTMLCode_Database doesn't return anything. Could it be a simple

```
function ReplaceHTMLCode_Database($content){
    return str_replace('{SELECT_CHAR}',GetPlayerSelect(),$content);
}
```

Please give some information about what the function should do.